# How add line above PCB top overlay string in Altium?

Tags: altium

How can I add an inverting above my Top Overlay String in Altium? The forward-slash and backward-slash do not work with the string-object in the PCB designer. In the schematic designer it is not a problem. I did not find anything on the Altium website.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283152/how-i-can-add-top-line-to-text-in-altium

Comment: @Andyaka you can see in the post that I tried this

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible using the same method in the schematic, but it is possible with a different approach.

**Option 1)** use an online font generator, such as https://fsymbols.com/generators/overline/

Type in the partial string that you want overlined, then copy/paste (It's font dependent, and looks awful)

[image]

**Option 2)** Draw a line then create a union from string and line for easy positioning. Looks better and way faster.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid that I am gonna need to hack it like this. But who will know :) Thanks anyway

Comment: you could also use a 'fill' if you want defined corners instead of the rounded ends of a 'line'; depends on your text size I suppose.

Comment: Put in a bug request to change it